# Matlab : Reading strings and numbers to workspace

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, file

so this is my excel file test.xlsx

```
have    1.44E+12    33   noChange   1.44E+12
four    1.44E+12    466  noChange   1.44E+12
have    1.44E+12    467  noChange   1.44E+12
four    1.44E+12    100  noChange   1.44E+12
minutes 1.44E+12    666  noChange   1.44E+12
```

I used `EyeT = xlsread(test.xlsx)`
and im getting the numbers right, but `NaN` for the string values.
Is there any other function to read it? Textscan maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the three outputs of [`xlsread`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). Here's an example:

Excel file:

```
have    1   aa  5
four    2   bb  6
have    3   bb  67
```

Matlab code:

```
>> [num, txt, raw] = xlsread('test.xls') 
num =
     1   NaN     5
     2   NaN     6
     3   NaN    67
txt = 
    'have'    ''    'aa'
    'four'    ''    'bb'
    'have'    ''    'bb'
raw = 
    'have'    [  1]    'aa'     [  5]
    'four'    [  2]    'bb'     [  6]
    'have'    [  3]    'bb'     [ 67]
    [ NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]    [NaN]
```

As you can see, `num` is a matrix containing the numbers, and `NaN` for strings; `txt` is a cell array of strings, with `''` for numbers; and `raw` is a cell array containing numbers and strings.

Comment: I seem to lose precision while storing numbers :s Like it shows that the column is filled with same number. But its different in my input file

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304018/matlab-storing-large-numbers/31304433?noredirect=1#comment50599303_31304433