# Matlab : Storing large numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, file, csv

My csv file looks like this

```
'have', 1436271616097.0, 33.0, 'noChange', 1436271538982.0
'four', 1436271616130.0, 466.0, 'noChange', 1436271538982.0
'have', 1436271616596.0, 467.0, 'noChange', 1436271538982.0
'four', 1436271617063.0, 100.0, 'noChange', 1436271538982.0
```

I tried using `[num, txt, raw] = csvread('test.csv')`
it shows error saying Too many output arguments.

i tried converting my csv file to .xlsx but then it changes the numbers to this,

```
have    1.44E+12    33   noChange   1.44E+12
four    1.44E+12    466  noChange   1.44E+12
have    1.44E+12    467  noChange   1.44E+12
four    1.44E+12    100  noChange   1.44E+12
minutes 1.44E+12    666  noChange   1.44E+12
```

then i used `[num, txt, raw] = xlsread('test.xls')`
but the problem is that if i display `eyeT = vpa(eyeT(:,1))` it shows same float value. how can i use textscan for this?

Comment: if you look at the [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html), csvread only have 1 output argument

Comment: so is there a way to store large numbers without csvread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as a short example using `textscan` for the mentioned csv-file. This gives you a cell array for each column.

```
% reading the data
file = fopen('file.csv');
F = textscan(file,'%s %f %f %s %f','Delimiter',',');

format long    % to show all the digits of the large number
celldisp(F)    % display the values of all cells
```

*This is the result:*

```
F{1}{1} =
'have'
F{1}{2} =
'four'
F{1}{3} =
'have'
F{1}{4} =
'four'
F{2} =
   1.0e+12 *
   1.436271616097000
   1.436271616130000
   1.436271616596000
   1.436271617063000
F{3} =
    33
   466
   467
   100
F{4}{1} =
'noChange'
F{4}{2} =
'noChange'
F{4}{3} =
'noChange'
F{4}{4} =
'noChange'
F{5} =
   1.0e+12 *
   1.436271538982000
   1.436271538982000
   1.436271538982000
   1.436271538982000
```

Comment: Hey thanks man! but my f{2} shows F{2}

ans =

  1.0e+012 *

   1.436270000000000
   1.436270000000000
   1.436270000000000
   1.436270000000000
   1.436270000000000
   1.436270000000000

Comment: @HarshSharma: You can try replacing the format specifier with `%f64` or something else defined [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#input_argument_formatspec).